# Click on HTML element on iframe

Tags: php, jquery, html, iframe, xpath

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Get xpath location of element in iframe(iframe from my domain)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8524621/get-xpath-location-of-element-in-iframeiframe-from-my-domain)

I have a javascript function to get xpath as result (getXPath) and below is the code. Also I have a an external site in iframe but I show him when I use proxy (code is below). And I have a jquery function to show me xpath when I click on some element in iframe but Dont work. What is problem:

CODE:

```
<?php 

error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE); 

$url = $_GET['url']; 

if( ! empty($url)) 
{ 
    $data = file_get_contents($url); 

    $data = str_replace('<head>', '<head><base href="'.$url.'" /></base>', $data); 

    $data = preg_replace('#<script(.*?)>(.*?)</script>#is', '', $data); 
    $data = preg_replace('#<iframe(.*?)></iframe>#is', '', $data); 

    $data .=  
    ' 
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script> 
    <script> 
    $("div").each(function(i){ 
        if($(this).css("position") == "fixed") $(this).css("display", "none"); 
    }); 
    </script> 
    ' 
    ; 

    die($data);  
} 

?> 
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd"> 
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en"> 
<head> 
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" /> 
    <meta name="author" content="Webarto" /> 

    <title>AdriaMart</title> 

<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script> 
//function for xpath location
<script type="text/javascript">
    function getXPath(node, path) {
        path = path || [];
        if(node.parentNode) {
          path = getXPath(node.parentNode, path);
        }

        if(node.previousSibling) {
          var count = 1;
          var sibling = node.previousSibling
          do {
            if(sibling.nodeType == 1 && sibling.nodeName == node.nodeName) {count++;}
            sibling = sibling.previousSibling;
          } while(sibling);
          if(count == 1) {count = null;}
        } else if(node.nextSibling) {
          var sibling = node.nextSibling;
          do {
            if(sibling.nodeType == 1 && sibling.nodeName == node.nodeName) {
              var count = 1;
              sibling = null;
            } else {
              var count = null;
              sibling = sibling.previousSibling;
            }
          } while(sibling);
        }

        if(node.nodeType == 1) {
          path.push(node.nodeName.toLowerCase() + (node.id ? "[@id='"+node.id+"']" : count > 0 ? "["+count+"]" : ''));
        }
        return path;
      };

</script>

//function to get  xpath location and write in textfield in focus
***<script>

    $('#iframe').ready(function () {
        var selectedtextbox;
$('input[name="myinput"]').focus(function(){selectedtextbox=$(this);});
        $('div, p, li, a, href').click(function () { 
           var xpath = getXPath(this);
            selectedtextbox.val(xpath)
        });
    });
</script>***
<style type="text/css"> 
<!-- 
iframe{width:100%;height:400px;} 
--> 
</style> 

</head> 
<body> 

<!-- ... -->
<input id="iframe_url" name="" type="text" />
<input id="iframe_button" name="" type="button" />
<iframe id="iframe" src="?url=http://kupime.com"></iframe>
<script type="text/javascript">
  document.getElementById('iframe_button').onclick = function () {
    document.getElementById('iframe').src = '?url=' + document.getElementById('iframe_url').value;
  };
</script>
<!-- ... -->
//Textfields for xpath location to write inside them
<input id="" name="myinput" type="text" value="">
<input id="" name="myinput" type="text" value="">
<input id="" name="myinput" type="text" value="">



</body> 
</html>
```

***

```
    $('#iframe').ready(function () {
        var selectedtextbox;
$('input[name="myinput"]').focus(function(){selectedtextbox=$(this);});
        $('div, p, li, a, href').click(function () { 
           var xpath = getXPath(this);
            selectedtextbox.val(xpath)
        });
    });
</script>***
```

Comment: The problem is jquery code above $(#iframe').ready ... ... where is the error here!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 3 issues.

1. the iframe-element is not accessible at this point(the function is placed above the iframe, the #iframe-element is still unknown)
2. ready will fire when the current document is ready, not the document within the iframe. Use load instead
3. you need to set the document within the iframe as context-argument

---

```
//wait for ready in the current document to have access to #iframe
$(function()
  {
    $('#iframe')
      //observe the load-event of the iframe-element
      .on('load',
          function () 
          {
            //set a default-input to avoid errors
            var selectedtextbox=$('input[name="myinput"]:eq(0)');
            $('input[name="myinput"]')
              .focus(function(){selectedtextbox=$(this);});
            //Note the 2nd argument here, 
            //it sets the contextof $() to the document inside the iframe
            $('div, p, li, a, href',
              this.contentWindow.document)
                .click(function () 
                       { 
                          var xpath = getXPath(this);
                          selectedtextbox.val(xpath)
                       });
            });
    });
```